# How to put void link like Html <a href="#"> in Ember using <LinkTo @route="">

Tags: ember.js

I would like to know if it's possible to make a temporary void link in Ember `<LinkTo @route="">` like HTML `<a href="#">`, thanks for helping.

Comment: I get what you're looking for but I'm honestly not aware of a simple one character fix (i.e. `#`) that would work. If you know the route name, you could just set the `@route` attribute to the current route, and that should produce a similar effect. Otherwise, you could pull the name in your component/controller using a router service.

But I don't feel like that's the idea solution you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

While `<LinkTo>` provides some interesting features when you use it with a route (navigation without reloading, active route recognizing, query param and model passing). You don't need to use it to create a link. You can use `<a href="#">` directly in a template with no ill effects if it is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @jrjohnson I want just to know if there's a way to do it.

Comment: The route is a required param, I guess you could make a route that is `#`, but adding some reasons why to this question would help me understand what the purpose is. If the purpose is to create the href you describe then using `<LinkTo>` isn't a good choice for that.

Comment: Initially, when we create app design, we begin juste with some unknown links name, example for the main menu (link1 link 2 link3), so I don't have to create those routes link1, link2...  and   delete them after, in my logic, since I'm  working with ember I try most of the time to use its components, there for the purpose is that sometime we don't need to create route for an void link.

Comment: I agree that you should use `<a href="#">` as a placeholder until you have routes to route to :)

Comment: One of the really great things about Ember is the HTML first approach. So you can start with empty `<a>` tags and then turn them into `<LinkTo>` when you have a route. The output of `<LinkTo>` has some more attributes, but doesn't have any extra markup (divs/spans/etc). So you can expect it to stay the same when you switch. It's hard to get used to when moving from other frameworks / systems, but starting with plain HTML is almost always a really good idea with Ember.js.